# how can we delete fields from document firebase firstore I am working with angular firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, field

basically I'm trying to restructure all the docs in my collection I have updated but I still have previous fields I want to remove them

These two code snippets are not working for me

```
const userRef = doc(db, "users/dWE72sOcV1CRuA0ngRt5");

// Remove "age" field from the document
await updateDoc(userRef, {
  "age": deleteField()
});
```

and

```
// get the reference to the doc
let docRef=this.db.doc(`ProfileUser/${userId}/followersCount/FollowersCount`);

// remove the {currentUserId} field from the document
let removeCurrentUserId = docRef.update({
    [currentUserId]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
});
```

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please include imports, firebase version and wrap `update`'s in a try catch block and provide the resulting error

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing `@angular/fire` methods with `firebase` methods ? For this to work I have tested with importing `doc`, `updateDoc`, `deleteField`  methods from `@angular/fire/firestore` and it worked. For deleting many fields from many documents you can use this [**`snippet`**](https://gist.github.com/Rohit1024/1f962981737cff9fcb355dc2d5e14f14)

Comment: @RohitKharche Thank you for this, point I was confused about that and now it worked for me when I imported all the required methods. my deleteField method was not importing properly now it worked

Comment: As it worked for you I will post as an answer so that other community members will also get the answer for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some method names are the same for both `@angular/fire` and `firebase` sdk. So make sure you import methods from 1 sdk only means don’t mix the methods of these SDKs.

Imports :

```
import { Firestore, doc, updateDoc, deleteField } from '@angular/fire/firestore'; // ⇐ imported form same SDK not from firebase SDK
const db = Firestore;
const userRef = doc(db, "users/dWE72sOcV1CRuA0ngRt5");

// Remove "age" field from the document
await updateDoc(userRef, {
  "age": deleteField()
});
```

Like you mentioned you want to delete some fields from many documents for that you can use batch updates with `deleteField()` on the fields you want to delete as follows:

```
import { collection, query, getDocs, writeBatch, deleteField } from "firebase/firestore"; // ⇐ this time all are imported from firebase SDK instead of `@angular/fire`.
const db = Firestore;
async function deleteFields() {
  const ref = collection(db, "mocks");
  const q = query(ref);
  getDocs(q).then((snapshots) => {
    const batch = writeBatch(db);
    snapshots.forEach((snap) => {
      batch.update(snap.ref, {
        address: deleteField(),
        [currentUserId] : deleteField(), // ⇐ you and add more fields here.
      });
    });
    return batch.commit();
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Fields deleted successfully");
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error deleting fields: ", error);
  })
}
```

But here make sure you are selecting the fields you want to delete.

Reference : [**`DeleteField`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields)

Comment: Answer also applies to using the Firestore Lite SDK `firebase/firestore/lite`. Using linting rules helps as this is really easy to do. Example `"no-restricted-imports":  ["error", { "paths" : [ { "name": "@angular/fire/firestore", "message": "Please use firebase/firestore/lite instead." } ] }]`

Comment: @AndrewAllen Yes that is also good idea to avoid such problems :).